# Strange error with preferences

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain where my error is and maybe how I can fix it? All information in screenshots.

In one activity:

[image]

In another activity:

[image]

Logs:

```
06-13 04:09:07.378 24123-24123/com.roadtob E/test: Not logged in
06-13 04:09:09.058 24123-24123/com.roadtob E/test: Username
```

I don't have any ideas about why that doesn't work.

Comment: Well for starters, post the code in here instead of linking screenshots.

Comment: @Razgriz
I know about this function, but in this situation simplier use links in my opinion. 
Sorry if it's not the best idea.

Comment: @V.Govorov Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I bet that you are using `Activity.getPreferences(int)` ... now read the documentation of this method ... if you still don't get it  then read the doc until you get

Comment: @Selvin Ok. How can I get preferences for all application?

Comment: read SharedPreferences doc ... + some guides(always prefer the official once first) about accessing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
// save data
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", "not logged in");
editor.commit();

// retrieve data
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String test = sharedpreferences.getString("username", "not logged in");
```

You can also check [this tutorial on SharedPreference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: Thanks alot) For your help/
I already made it without help, but thanks)